# Haskell Random from Datatype

Tags: haskell, random

Im pretty new to Haskell.
I have a datatype:

```
data Sentence= Prop Int
          | No Sentence
          | And [Sentence]
          | Or [Sentence]
          deriving Eq
```

I already wrote a Show instance for it

However, whether it makes sense or not, I would like to be able to generate a random Sentence.
How can i accomplish this in Haskell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Random number generation is a typical example of an "impure" operation, since calling a random generator twice will of course yield different results - Haskell's nature disallows this.

Therefore, you need to use a so called monad `Gen a` that represents a *random generator, that, when run, yields a value of type `a`*.

Fortunately, you can combine these generators in a quite nice syntax ...

So, you just need some [library](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Hierarchical_libraries/Randoms#Using_QuickCheck_to_Generate_Random_Data) that implements such a generator - and here we go.

```
randomNo   = No <$> randomSentence
randomProp = Prop <$> choose (1, 10) 
[...]

randomSentence = oneOf [randomNo, randomProp, ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the superfast response, but what do you mean by <$> ?

Comment: Ah, it's from `Control.Applicative` - just some simplified syntax that means you can apply a function to a random value.

Comment: ah ok, however, when i test your code, Haskell says: 
Not in scope: `oneOf'
But it should be in Quickcheck right?

Comment: Yep, you'll need *Test.QuickCheck* and *System.Random* (*Control.Applicative* and *Control.Monad* are also quite nice for some extra functionality/syntax)

Comment: Strange, it recognises the imports, but still it doesnt recognise oneOf somehow

Comment: Yes, indeed it should be there.

Comment: Ah, its oneof, not oneOf :P how stupid of me...
im puzzling how to get the Gen Sentence printed

Comment: See the quickcheck documentation: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.1.0.3/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html. Call `unGen` to unpack the generator function then run it. The first argument is a `StdGen` from `System.Random`. The next argument is "size" (which will control how big your results are).

Comment: If you use QC2 then there should be a `sample` function so you don't need to worry about `StdGen` or `unGen` at all (if you don't want to).

Answer (score 5):

My favorite method is to use the [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) package.  Although it boils down to the same thing as passing some `RandomGen` around, it does it for you and ensures that you don't mess up in the process (such as passing an already-used generator).  Further, `Rand StdGen a` has the nice interpretation of  "a probability distribution of `a`s".

For your example, it might look like this:

```
-- a type for probability distributions
type Dist = Rand StdGen

-- pick uniformly between a list of values
uniform :: [a] -> Dist a
uniform xs = do
    ix <- getRandomR (0, length xs - 1)
    return (xs !! ix)

-- return a list of elements generated by the given distribution
randList :: Int -> Dist a -> Dist [a]
randList maxElems dist = do
    elems <- getRandomR (0, maxElems)
    sequence (replicate elems dist)

-- return a probability distribution of sentences
randSentence :: Dist Sentence
randSentence = do
    -- choose one of these four distributions by a uniform distribution
    -- (uniform [...] returns a distribution of distributions)
    dist <- uniform [
        Prop <$> getRandom,
        No <$> randSentence,
        And <$> randList 5 randSentence,
        Or <$> randList 5 randSentence ]
    -- and sample the one we chose
    dist
```

Note the magic number 5 up there.  That's so we don't get 2 billion element lists.  You might want to tweak the distribution of the number of terms in your randomly generated lists.

And to run it you can use `evalRandIO` or many other things, say like:

```
main = print =<< evalRandIO randSentence
```

Comment: Thanks!
I found that the Monad.Random library is not included in the latest windows package. perhaps for a reason? Since when I copy-paste the source from it (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/NewMonads/MonadRandom) into an own file, it gives me errors of which i have no idea how to solve it:Illegal instance declaration for `MonadState s (RandT g m)'

Comment: You need to install via cabal, not copy and paste.  I assume you have Haskell Platform installed.  Then exectute `cabal install MonadRandom` at the command prompt.  You may need to `cabal update` first.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the module [`System.Random`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/random-1.0.0.2/System-Random.html), it's in the random package, so you probably have to install it first.

This module defines to typeclasses:

```
class RandomGen g where
  next :: g -> (Int,g)
  -- ...

class Random r where
  random ::  RandomGen g => g -> (a,g)
  randomR :: RandomGen g => (r,r) -> g -> (a, g)
```

The typeclass, you have to implement is Random, specific the first function (as the second makes no sense, you can just implement like `randomR = const random`. What does `random`? You get a random generator as input, you have to generate what you need for it, and give the new generator back.

To generate your random values, you could either use the `State` monad, or something like this:

```
random g = (myResult,gn) where
  (random1,g1) = next g
  (random2,g2) = next g2
  -- ...
```

You can then use the systems random generator by this function:

```
randomIO :: Random r => IO r
```

It is predefined and yields a different value each call.

However, finally you have to decide yourself how to define your Random instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
pick :: [a] -> IO a
pick xs = randomRIO (0, length xs - 1) >>= return . (xs !!)
```

Run pick over any list.