# Generate a random value from a user-defined data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, random

**Similar: [Haskell Random from Datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769193/haskell-random-from-datatype)**

I have created a data type to contain the different weapons in the Rock Paper Scissor game.

```
data Weapon = Rock | Paper | Scissor
```

Now I would like to generate a random weapon which will be used by the computer against the user.
I have take a look at the similar link I posted at the beginning but It seems too general for me.

I am able to generate random numbers from any other type. What I can get my head around is how to make my data type an instance of the Random class.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To generate a random `Weapon`, whether you make `Weapon` an instance of `Random` or not, what you need is a way to map numbers to `Weapon`s. If you derive `Enum` for the type, a map to and from `Int`s is defined by the compiler. So you could define

```
randomWeapon :: RandomGen g => g -> (Weapon, g)
randomWeapon g = case randomR (0,2) g of
                   (r, g') -> (toEnum r, g')
```

for example. With an `Enum` instance, you can also easily make `Weapon` an instance of `Random`:

```
instance Random Weapon where
    random g = case randomR (0,2) g of
                 (r, g') -> (toEnum r, g')
    randomR (a,b) g = case randomR (fromEnum a, fromEnum b) g of
                        (r, g') -> (toEnum r, g')
```

If there is a possibility of adding or removing constructors from the type, the best way to keep the bounds for `randomR` in sync with the type is to also derive `Bounded`, as [Joachim Breitner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946226/joachim-breitner) [immediately suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811498/generate-a-random-value-from-a-user-defined-data-type-in-haskell/11811809#comment15699776_11811809):

```
data Weapon
    = Rock
    | Paper
    | Scissors
      deriving (Bounded, Enum)

instance Random Weapon where
    random g = case randomR (fromEnum (minBound :: Weapon), fromEnum (maxBound :: Weapon)) g of
                 (r, g') -> (toEnum r, g')
    randomR (a,b) g = case randomR (fromEnum a, fromEnum b) g of
                        (r, g') -> (toEnum r, g')
```

Comment: With an additional derived Bounded instance, you can make the code completely abstract.

Comment: What if I add a new weapon? Is there a general way to know the number of different values that I data type can have?

Comment: Then also deriving `Bounded` is the simplest way to keep things in sync. Updating answer.

Answer (score 8):

While Daniel Fischer's `Enum` approach is certainly a good general way of doing this, it's not *really* necessary to use an explicit mapping from `Int`s. You can as well do just

```
instance Random Weapon where
  random g = case random g of
               (r,g') | r < 1/3    = (Rock    , g')
                      | r < 2/3    = (Paper   , g')
                      | otherwise  = (Scissors, g')
```

using the `Double` instance of `Random`. This is less efficient than with a derived `Enum` instance, but more flexible – for instance, you could easily define a nonequal distribution

```
  random g = case random g of
               (r,g') | r < 1/4    = (Rock    , g')
                      | r < 1/2    = (Paper   , g')
                      | otherwise  = (Scissors, g')
```

where `Scissors` is more likely than the other two. Of course, you should only do such a thing if the nonequal distribution is in some way canonical for your data type, certainly not in this example.

Comment: [`randomR`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomR) says it expects uniform distribution among the possible outputs. For non-uniform distribution, it's probably best to implement a separate function so as to avoid breaking that typeclass contract.

Comment: @4castle that typeclass contract doesn't really hold up anyway though. For e.g. `Double`, “uniform” is understood in the sense of a continuous distribution – i.e., the _probability density_ on the real line is constant. Makes sense for sure. However, the real line is not uniformly _sampled_ by floating-point values, hence if you'd actually look at the distribution of the binary-distinct individual `Double` values, you would note that `0.8346253987632499` occurs much more often than `0.0000003265368256732462`.

Comment: But yeah, for “conceptually discrete” types like `Weapon` I'd agree.

Answer (score 8):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances,
 ScopedTypeVariables, OverlappingInstances #-}

import System.Random

class (Bounded a, Enum a) => BoundedEnum a
instance (Bounded a, Enum a) => BoundedEnum a
instance BoundedEnum a => Random a where
   random gen = randomR (minBound :: a, maxBound :: a) gen
   randomR (f, t) gen =
     (toEnum r :: a, nextGen)
     where
       (rnd, nextGen) = next gen
       r = fromEnum f + (rnd `mod` length [f..t])
```

Now you can say:

```
r <- randomIO :: Anything
```

where Anything must be an instance of classes Enum and Bounded.

Comment: What's the reason for defining `BoundedEnum` rather than just directly using `(Bounded a, Enum a) => Random a`?

Comment: @huon – although this post is quite old, I would suspect it is to avoid creating an orphan instance (https://wiki.haskell.org/Orphan_instance), which can be problematic.

Comment: Note that `next` is now deprecated

Answer (score 2):

If you have a generator for the data then you can use `oneof` from Test.QuickCheck.Gen

Answer (score 1):

A coworker suggested to me an alternative to Alekseev's solution which I find a little bit more readable (I'm still learning Haskell so it's probably more on the reader than the code).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Bounded a, Enum a) => Random a where
  random = randomR (minBound, maxBound)

  randomR (f, t) gen =
    let (rndInt, nxtGen) = randomR (fromEnum f, fromEnum t) gen
     in (toEnum rndInt, nxtGen)

data Weapon = Rock | Paper | Scissor deriving (Eq, Show, Ord, Bounded, Enum)
```

You could then do: `getRandomWeapon = randomRIO (minBound, maxBound) :: IO Weapon` and then extract one with `weaponChoice <- getRandomWeapon`